# How I use RegExp replace template with ${var}?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example:

Using /\${key}/ as regular string is ok, replacement was success

but using string '${key}' directly, the answer is not I want

Would it be slower if I use split and join ?

```
let tp1 = "XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}";
tp1 = tp1.replace(new RegExp(/\${key}/, 'g'), 'AA');
console.log(tp1)

let tp2 = "XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}";
tp2 = tp2.replace(new RegExp('${key}', 'g'), 'AA');
console.log(tp2)

let tp3 = "XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}";
tp3 = tp3.split(`\${key}`).join('AA')
console.log(tp3)
```

```
Answer:
tp1: XXXAAXXXAAXXXAAXXXAA
tp2: XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}
tp3: XXXAAXXXAAXXXAAXXXAA
```

Answer (score 4):

`$` means end of string in regex, that's why you need to escape it with `\`. If you use a constructor with a regex string, you need to double escape it: `'\\${key}'` so that it stays a backslash in the string

```js
let tp1 = "XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}";
tp1 = tp1.replace(new RegExp(/\${key}/, 'g'), 'AA');
console.log(tp1)

let tp2 = "XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}";
tp2 = tp2.replace(new RegExp('\\${key}', 'g'), 'AA');
console.log(tp2)

let tp3 = "XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}";
tp3 = tp3.split(`\${key}`).join('AA')
console.log(tp3)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect!

Comment: @MaheerAli yeah there are double escaping considerations in SO question/answers too :P

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a regex, consider defining a *function* that takes in the `key` and returns the replaced string, allowing you to use template literals:

```js
const insertKey = (key) => `XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}`;
console.log(
  insertKey('AA'),
  insertKey('foo')
);
```

Comment: In fact, `XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}` is a fixed template

Comment: If you want to use it as a template literal, you have to surround it in backtick delimiters, but template literals are evaluated as soon as the interpreter comes across them - you can't define a template literal up front and then pass a variable to it later. For something like that, better to use a function that returns a template literal

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it as placeholder you just have to use different quotes `` instead of ''

```js
let key = 'BB';
let tp2 = "XXXBBXXXBBXXXBBXXXBB";
tp2 = tp2.replace(new RegExp(`${key}`, 'g'), 'AA');
console.log(tp2); //XXXAAXXXAAXXXAAXXXAA

key = '\\${key}';
let tp3 = "XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}XXX${key}";
tp3 = tp3.replace(new RegExp(`${key}`, 'g'), 'AA');
console.log(tp3); //XXXAAXXXAAXXXAAXXXAA
```

Comment: Thanks, but our template must use '${}',We used ‘{{}}’ at once, but my boss want '${}',so...I have to change it...

Comment: I added one more example with ${} for you